# Callback function not receiving data after function returns data from API endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery

On-Click Function

```
$(".action-open-instruction-confirm").on("click",
    function(event) {

        var applicationNumber = $('.case-application-number').val();

        getInstructionType(applicationNumber, function(data) {
            $("#InstructionConfirm #instruction-confirm-instruction-type").html(data);
        });
    });
```

Endpoint function

```
function getInstructionType(applicationNumber) {
        if (window.location.port !== "") {
            port = ":" + window.location.port;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        var url = window.location.protocol +
            "//" +
            window.location.hostname +
            port +
            "-apiEndpoint-?applicationNumber=" +
            applicationNumber;

        $.get(url,
            function(data) {
                return data; //<-- Change this to $("#InstructionConfirm #instruction-confirm-instruction-type").html(data); and it works correctly
            });
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="InstructionConfirm">
    <span id="instruction-confirm-instruction-type"></span>
</div>
```

I have the two functions above that I am trying to use to alter the HTML of the `#instruction-confirm-instruction-type element present in my HTML. The problem is that at the moment the callback function doesn't seem to be functioning properly.

The On-Click function passes the `applicationNumber` to the `getInstructionType` function which then calls an API endpoint. This endpoint works correctly and returns the data with no issues. However it then seems like the `return data;` line in my `getInstructionType` function doesn't seem to be returning the data properly, as the callback function in the on-click is never executed.

I know the callback is not being executed as it doesn't trigger the breakpoint I have on the `$("#InstructionConfirm #instruction-confirm-instruction-type").html(data);` line.

If I then replace the `return data;` line in the second function with `$("#InstructionConfirm #instruction-confirm-instruction-type").html(data);`, then I get the behaviour I am expecting with no issues.

What exactly is preventing `getInstructionType` from returning the data to my callback function for it to be used within the on-click function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you don't do anything with the callback you provide. You don't create an argument in the function definition for it, and you don't call it from `$.get()`. Try this:

```js
$(".action-open-instruction-confirm").on("click", function(e) {
  var applicationNumber = $('.case-application-number').val();

  getInstructionType(applicationNumber, function(data) {
    $("#InstructionConfirm #instruction-confirm-instruction-type").html(data);
  });
});

function getInstructionType(applicationNumber, callback) { // accept the 'callback' argument
  if (window.location.port !== "") {
    port = ":" + window.location.port;
  } else {
    return null;
  }

  var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + "-apiEndpoint-?applicationNumber=" + applicationNumber;
  $.get(url, callback); // invoke the callback when $.get receives data
}
```

Also note that you can just use `location.origin` instead of manually building the protocol/domain/port string:

```
var url = window.location.origin + "-apiEndpoint-?applicationNumber=" + applicationNumber;
```

Although it looks like you may be missing a `/` after the port as your URL will currently include the string after the port which appears to be incorrect.

Comment: Ah I see where I've gone wrong. I'll adjust my code. I'm assuming this will also allow for the `getInstructionType` function to be reused in other parts of my code? Also the window.location.origin is really useful, thank you for that.

Comment: Yes, this will make code re-use much easier. No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't have a parameter for the callback:

```
function getInstructionType(applicationNumber) {
```

should be:

```
function getInstructionType(applicationNumber, callback) {
```

you can then add your callback

```
$.get(url,
      function(data) {
         if ($.isFunction(callback))
             callback(data);
      });
```

or even just:

```
$.get(url, callback)
```

---

You might like to consider using promises instead, eg:

```
$(".action-open-instruction-confirm").on("click",
  function(event) {
    var applicationNumber = $('.case-application-number').val();
    getInstructionType(applicationNumber).done(function(data) {
        $("#InstructionConfirm #instruction-confirm-instruction-type").html(data);
    });
});

function getInstructionType(applicationNumber) {
    ....  
    return $.get(url);
```